# grails Searchable plugin : How to make property only for sorting , but not for searching

Tags: grails-2.0, grails-plugin, grails-controller, compass-lucene, grails-searchable

I am using searchable plugin in my project. And i have a simple domain, which given below

```
    Class User {
        String title
        String Description
        int vote
        Date date
            }
    static searchable = {
            only: ['description','title','vote','date']
            date name: 'sortableTitle1', index: 'not_analyzed'
            vote name: 'sortableTitle2', index: 'not_analyzed'

}
```

My need is to make vote and date as a sortable element. and it should not regarded while searching
Also i know, it can done by using below code

```
date name: 'sortableTitle1', index: 'not_analyzed' store:'no'
```

But in this case the result list of object will not contain date property, so it can't be displayed in gsp for display.
 So how i can make 'date' element for displaying, sorting and not for searching in my gsp.

Comment: May be not the best thing to do, but this what I did for the the same kind of problem: I set a mapping for my class, and Searchable helped me to get Ids. With ids, I use getAll method get all objects (automatically sort with the mapping).

Comment: @ArrrghGrails how you set mapping for class

Answer (score 1):

I can't add new comment, so here is the next part of my answer:

> how you set mapping for class:

You can declare the default sort order for a collection in the mapping ([documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/GORM.html#defaultSortOrder)).

I hope it is what you need !

**Example found in the documentation:**

To "replace", for example, this:

```
def airports = Airport.list(sort:'name')
```

You can use

```
class Airport {
    …
    static mapping = {
        sort name: "desc"
    }
}
```

*And the the first part of my answer:*

> May be not the best thing to do, but this what I did for the the same
>   kind of problem: I set a mapping for my class, and Searchable helped
>   me to get Ids. With ids, I use getAll method get all objects
>   (automatically sort with the mapping).